# Why does $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I\cong k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/\mathrm{LT}(I)$ as $k$-vector spaces?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field, $I\trianglelefteq k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ an ideal and $\mathrm{LT}(I)$ the ideal generated by the leading terms of elements of $I$. We noted as a remark that $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I\cong k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/\mathrm{LT}(I)$ as $k$-vector spaces, but I can't see why that holds.

I know about that normal form map $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]\longrightarrow k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and that it has kernel $I$, but I don't know, if we can use this. Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: The normal form map I mean sends $f$ to the unique polynomial $f^\ast$ such that $f=f^\ast\bmod I$ and such that no term of $f^\ast$ lies in $\mathrm{LT}(I)$.

Edit 2: Let me also add what we wrote down as a proof:
"Every $f+I$ has a unique representative, none of whose terms lie in $\mathrm{LT}(I)$. QED"
But I don't really understand what the argument is.

Comment: The usual proof shows that the set of monomials which don't belong to $\mathrm{LT}(I)$ is a $k$-basis in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I$.

Comment: @user26857 thank you, I'll try that. I also added what we wrote down as a proof.

Comment: The key observation is that, since $LT(I)$ is a monomial ideal, a polynomial $p$ belongs to $LT(I)$ if and only if all the monomials that appear in $p$ with non-zero coefficient belong to $LT(I)$.